# Why is writing a newline to a text file not working in Python?

Tags: python, text-files, newline

I am trying to save the lists into the text file which each sentence on one line. But why are these codes not working for me? Anyone? Thank you.

```
import codecs

text = ["good morning", "hello everybody"] 

for texts in text:
    file = codecs.open("newlinetest.txt", "w", "utf-8")
    print texts
    file.write(texts + "\n")

file.close()
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are opening the file for each string in `text` without closing it, which is probably what causes your error (which you didn't mention).

Use `with` and don't bother with closing the file (and also don't name the file reference `file`, as it will shadow Python's built-in file). Also note that you will need to use `'a'` as the opening mode so you always appending to the file instead of truncating it:

```
import codecs

text = ["good morning", "hello everybody"] 

with codecs.open("newlinetest.txt", "a", "utf-8") as my_file:  # better not shadow Python's built-in file
    for texts in text:
         print texts
         my_file.write(texts + "\n")
# no need to call my_file.close() at all
```

Comment: Even if the OP closed it there would only be one line, since opening with write access (`'w'`) will overwrite existing contents.

Comment: @cdarke indeed, I missed that. I fixed my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to open the file once outside the loop and you can use str.join to write, `w` overwrites so you are overwriting each iteration ending up with only the last element from the list written:

```
import codecs

text = ["good morning", "hello everybody"]
with codecs.open("newlinetest.txt", "w", "utf-8") as f:
    f.write("\n".join(text))
```

Since you are passing a list, the csv module would be a good fit for what you want to do using a newline as the delimiter:

```
text = ["good morning", "hello everybody"]
import csv
with codecs.open("newlinetest.txt", "w", "utf-8") as f:
    wr = csv.writer(f,delimiter="\n")
    wr.writerow(text)
```

Answer (score 0):

Also use '\n\n' to induce newline spacing as the first '\n' parameter won't do anything but make sure the next input set starts on the next line.